# Is there a jQuery alternative to use the sessionStorage property in the header?

Tags: javascript, jquery, session-storage

Goal: when a user lands on the site with forms pre-filled in URL (e.g. zip code, phone number, etc.), the page will auto scroll the user to form at bottom of page with that already filled out. So basically, if the URL is something like www.site.com/?state=CA&zip=90210, it will scroll down to a form on that page.

I can do that now using sessionStorage **after** the header is fired off, but I would prefer to use such actually **in** the header for timing purposes. This is the code I have that fires after the main content, but before the footer output:

```html
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
 formParams = [
  ["firstname", "primary_firstname"],
  ["lastname", "primary_lastname"],
  ["phone", "primary_phone"],
  ["email", "primary_email"],
  ["zip", "primary_zip"]
 ];
 
 for (var i in formParams) {
  var formParam = formParams[i];
   for (var j = 0; j < formParam.length; j++) {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem(formParam[j]) !== null) {
     jQuery('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: jQuery("#scrollToHere").offset().top }, 2000);
     return;
   }
  }
 }
});
</script>
```

This works, but not in the header because there's nothing to store at that moment. Is there any way to execute such in the header? It's not mandatory for me to use the sessionStorage property.

Comment: What timing purposes are you talking about? What wrong behavior are you experiencing when you put this code in the header and what's the intended behavior?

Comment: You can't run a code referring to `body` or any elements in it in when the head section is being parsed. Those elements simply don't exist at that time.

Comment: @Khauri At the moment, I have to have the user fill out a form (i.e enter a zip code) on the page to take them to the form later on the page; I would like to have them be directed to the site from another / previous site where they already filled out that information.

Comment: So what `header` are you talking about here, exactly? The document header? The request header? The URL Search Params?

Comment: @Khauri I'm working in WordPress; it doesn't work in the header.php file, so this code is in the footer.php file. I'd like this to run off before the main content does, if possible.

Comment: What's the 'main content' in this case? And what error do you get when you run this in the head. ie, what "doesn't work" (check the console?) As @Teemu has said, because of how script tags are executed in order, if you were to put this in the head tag and remove the jquery.ready part, it won't be able to find your `#scrollToHere` element as it hasn't loaded in yet.

Comment: @Khauri Main content = body, and that now makes sense what Teemu was saying, thank you to both. Is there a better way to go about such (i.e. reading information from another site / URL params to scroll down to a section on another page), or will the information have to come from that page only?